# Why is my form submitting when I hit enter on a textbox?

Tags: javascript, forms

HTML:

```
<form name="prints" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="quantity_914" id="quantity_914" value="1" style="width:20px;" onblur="prints_change_quantity(event, this);" onkeyup="return prints_change_quantity(event, this); return false;" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function prints_change_quantity(e, element)
{
  var pid = element.id.replace('quantity_');

  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if("blur" == e.type || ("keyup" == e.type && code == 13)) 
  { 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(element.value);
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default `keyDown` event is triggered when you hit enter for a html form. Whenever you attach an event to `onkeyUp` attribute the form takes the enter key action and submits the form as it has no effect, however if you explicitly specify `onkeyDown` event then your `return prints_change_quantity(event, this);` gets called and hence the form won't get submitted . Change your html code to call the JavaScript function as shown below:

```
<form name="prints" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="quantity_914" id="quantity_914" value="1" style="width:20px;" onblur="prints_change_quantity(event, this);" onkeydown="return prints_change_quantity(event, this); return false;" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a keydown event won't stop a form from being submitted. You'll need to use keypress or keyup instead.

Answer (score 0):

use the key press event rather using keyup.

```
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handle" />
</form>

<script>
function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        alert("Enter was pressed was presses");
    }

    return false;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your existing function and don't want your form to submit you can just use jquery and prevent the form from submitting with your existing function.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jahumuciyo/2/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#prints").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent from submitting the form.
  });
});
```

I added an id of prints to the form alternatively you could use a name selector or some other selector...

Alternatively if you want to be able to submit the form at some point you could just add a jquery handler for keypress on the form and if its the return key cancel it.

```
$('#prints').keypress(function(e){    
 if ( e.which == 13 ) e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Example 2](http://jsbin.com/pafuvimisa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)